# Element style automatically added to slider div

Tags: javascript, image, slider

SO I have an image slider on my website.  On the source code, the div for every slider has a class but not element styles, however when I play the image slider and view the div via the firebug plugin in firefox as well as the firebug alternative on chrome, there is an element style that is automatically added to each div.  I've read articles saying that the javascript for the image slider will add a style to the php code but I've looked through the javascript and found nothing there.  For instance, the element style "left:" is added to the div for each slider but I can't find any property called "left:" in the javascript. I have no idea how the element style can be added.  Any ideas?  I'm trying to center the images in each slider but I can't because the element style gets in the way and makes the images not aligned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In your css.file add the !important to each given style that you do not want to be active.

```
.myElement
{
    left:  initial !important;
    right: initial !important;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. There's still a style="" appearing in each div and whenever the image changes in the slider, the values will change.  Don't know what's wrong.

Comment: But I figure out how to align the images by adjusting the css on the div container that was controlling the position of the actual slider.  It had an element on it but it was still adjustable via css so the element style didn't intervene.